# Is there a way to add a pallet with genesis config through a runtime upgrade?

Tags: runtime, runtime-upgrade, genesis

I have a chain running with some pallets in the runtime. Now I want to add a new (already existing) pallet in the runtime, but this pallet has some genesis config entries.

Is it possible to add this pallet in the runtime as part of a forkless upgrade?

One way I could think of achieving this is to use storage migrations which would populate the storage values needed for config items. Would this be a good practice or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a migration is the right way to do this.